# check if string starts with another string: find or compare?

Tags: c++, string, stl

If you want to know if a string starts with another, how would you do that in C++/STL? In Java there is `String.startsWith`, Python also has `string.startwith`, STL does not have a direct method for it. Instead, there are `std::string::find` and `std::string::compare`. Until now I used both methods, mostly depending on my current mood:

```
if ( str1.compare( 0, str2.length(), str2 ) == 0 )
    do_something();
if ( str1.find(str2) == 0 )
    do_something();
```

Of course, you could also do `str.substr(0,str2.length()) == str2`, maybe there are still some other ways do achieve the same. `find` is a bit handier than `compare`, but I have seen more people recommending `compare` that `find`.

But which one is *preferred*? Is there a performance difference? Is it implementation-dependent (GCC, VC++, etc)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The disadvantage of `find` is that if `str1` is long, then it will pointlessly search all the way through it for `str2`. I've never noticed an optimizer being smart enough to realise that you only care whether the result is 0 or not, and stop searching after the start of `str1`.

The disadvantage of `compare` is that you need to check that `str2.length()` is no greater than `str1.length()` (or catch the resulting exception and treat it as a false result).

Disappointingly, the closest thing to what you want in the standard library is `std::strncmp` (and of course you need to use `c_str()` with that), hence the need for `boost::starts_with` or your own equivalent which includes the bounds checks.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So if I don't know the length of str1, it would be better to use boost's `starts_with`. Else, if I know str1 will always be larger, but not too much larger than str2, `find` and `compare` will also be fine. Right?

Comment: @craesh: yes, if the disadvantage doesn't affect you then either `find` or `compare` gives the correct answer, so either is fine. There are plenty of situations where an extra pass over a string is negligible.

Comment: @SteveJessop likewise there are plenty of situations where c_str may need to perform a copy or where the string is long, which makes the check very expensive

Comment: @Foo Bah: I haven't actually trawled through any source lately, but I doubt that there are many implementations where `c_str()` makes a copy - normally they nul-terminate the string data in place. Of course I wouldn't *rely* on `c_str` to not make a copy, and that's part of the reason it's disappointing that `strncmp` is the closest in the standard library. But I don't think it will make the check expensive in practice, just theoretically might-be expensive.

Comment: @SteveJessop the other caveat with using the `C` string family is that you can't compare strings with null characters.  Though these are pedants and may not be relevant in this case.

Comment: @Foo Bah: it's a good point, though, `strncmp` isn't equivalent, just close.

Comment: I accepted your answer for being the most detailed one, although there were other good answers as well (sorry guys!). Thanks!

Comment: +1 However in my tests it seems that an exception is only thrown by compare() if the specified starting position is beyond the end of str1.  No exception seems to be thrown when str2 is longer than str1.

Answer (score 9):

boost has an algorithm `starts_with` which implements it fairly efficiently: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/starts_with.html

There is no requirement regarding how STL implementations must implement find or compare, other than the standard stuff (return values ...), so it is entirely implementation dependent.

Comment: Ah, didn't know that one! But I think, `str1.find(str2) == 0` still reads a little bit better than `starts_with(str1,str2)`. Maybe that's just a matter of taste...

Comment: @craesh at the end of the day, the person using your program couldn't care about the underlying code's appearance :)

Comment: @craesh: well, it's a matter of how much you're willing to pay for good taste :-)

Comment: Of course, my customers will never pay me for nice code or good taste :) But once you look into code you wrote a year ago, you want to understand what you wrote by just looking at it. You can't comment everything, so code should be verbose (not always possible).

Answer (score 9):

Since `find()` might have to search through the whole `string` no matter what, you can wrap `compare()` like this if you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool starts_with(const string& s1, const string& s2) {
    return s2.size() <= s1.size() && s1.compare(0, s2.size(), s2) == 0;
}

int main() {
    const string s("zipzambam");
    cout << starts_with(s, "zip") << endl;
}
```

Comment: Ok, but this will get exactly the same as when using `boost::algorithm::starts_with`. So this solution might be a fallback in case you can't access Boost, right?

Comment: FWIW, when `Y` is type  `bool`, `return X ? Y : false;` is equivalent to `return X && Y;`, and the latter is a bit more concise. So, `return s2.size() <= s1.size() && s1.compare(0, s2.size(), s2) == 0;`

Comment: @SteveJessop Indeed. Fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`find` may have to search through the entire string looking for matches even if the first character doesn't match, so I would suggest `compare`, or as mentioned by @Foo Bah you could use boost's `starts_with` algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`std::mismatch`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/mismatch/), the only *stupid* thing with this algorithm is that you have to ensure that the first range is smaller or equal to the second range.